# Removing items from list given a list of indices where items occur - Haskell

Tags: haskell

I'm trying to remove items from a list given the indices they occur at. Heres what i've done so far:

```
count   :: Eq a => [a] -> [a] -> [Int]
count s1 s2 = findIndices(`elem` s1) s2
```

If called like this: count "FOOOTBALL" "OREO" it will return [1,2] since the intersection of the two strings is 'O' so it will return the list of indices where this character occurs but it wont count the extra 'O' because there's only two 'O' in "OREO", I'm just explaining this to give more context.
So what i want to do now is get this list of indices that is returned and then remove every character occurring at the indices from the list. But i have no idea how to do this since i just started learning Haskell. Any help would be appreciated Thanks!

Comment: Why exactly do you need indices? Just do like `foldl (\r c -> delete c r) "FOOOTBALL" "OREO"` which would give `"FOTBALL"`. Or simply `foldl (flip delete)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since the indices to be removed are sorted, you can run down the list, keeping track of the current index, removing elements when the head of the indices list matches the current index.  If they match, you discard the head of both the list of indices and the list of elements.  If they do not match, you emit the element, and process the remainder of the list.  If you run out of indices before you reach the end of the list of elements, you simply return the remainder of the list of elements.

```
removeIndices :: [Int] -> [a] -> [a]
removeIndices = go 0 where
    go j (i:is) (a:as) | i == j = go (j+1) is as
                       | otherwise = a : go (j+1) (i:is) as
    go _ _ as = as
```

Answer (score 1):

With package `data-ordlist`'s [`minusBy :: (a -> b -> Ordering) -> [a] -> [b] -> [a]`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/data-ordlist-0.4.7.0/docs/Data-List-Ordered.html#v:minusBy),

```
> import qualified Data.List.Ordered as O

> map fst $ O.minusBy (\(_,i) j -> compare i j) (zip "Hello, World!" [1..]) [2,5,9]
"Hll, Wrld!"
```

The comparing function can also be written as `(compare . snd)`, if you prefer.